# Angular Material - Unable to divide header into two columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Angular version ~5 .. I have got one header but I want two headers (as shown below)

Can any please assist?
Here is the snippet...

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="selected">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> 
    <mat-checkbox (change)="AllItemsChange($event)" [(checked)]="selectAllItems">Students</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]=group.selected>{{group.name}}</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This is what I have currently got.
[image]

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple header0cell and mat-cell combos inside mat-table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Student </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="score">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Score </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.score}} </td>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```